# Retrieve Post by Custom Query String identified by meta_key and meta_value in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, custom-fields

Ok... Looking forward to your help.

Environment: IIS 6, PHP Version 5.3.28, Wordpress 3.8

I am trying to get single post via a Custom Query string. The query string is "storyid".
example http://localhost.com/?storyid=1234

"Storyid" is the custom field(meta_key) that is tied to each post.

I have done httpd redirect, I have made wp functions, I have even tried to reset wp_query.

I have used wp_query, meta_query, query_vars.

It feels like I'm close but I just keep getting 404 page not found or blank pages.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code below and also utilized a helicon rewritre regular expression.

```
    <?php
    $args1 = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(      
     array(
        'key' => 'nameofqueryvar',

    'value' => $_GET["nameofqueryvar"],
        'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

    global $myposts;

    if (is_page('Story')){

    $myposts = get_posts($args1); }
    ?>

    <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
   the_content();
    ?>
```